# Why does this MySQL query not work?

Tags: sql, mysql, database

mysql

```
create temporary table t2 
select min(id) 
from mycontent 
group by download_link;
```

ERROR 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

Comment: How large is the *mycontent* table?

Comment: I'm guessing here, but isn't the group by clause superfluous?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `mycontent` table may be locked by some other transaction when you trying to select from it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try doing them separately.

```
1) create temporary table t2;

2) select min(id) from mycontent group by download_link;
```

It's worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand group_by, you need to select the grouped fields for the query to make sense. What is it that you try to accomplish?

Imagine this table:

```
download_link, id
-----------------
''           , 3
'foo'        , 3
```

This, using your query, would select

```
3
3
```

and therefor explain your locking problem because row 1 is locked by the transaction already but needs to be replaced by row 2.